# Sanded and stained a pine window shelf... water damaged areas too dark. How to fix?

Tags: wood, staining, refinishing

I am prepping my house to sell.

We sanded and stained a window shelf under a Bay Window and the water damaged areas came out too dark. So how should I fix this? Sand again or stripper, or just cover over with gel stain?

I'm reading that I could apply a dilute finish before staining to reduce the blotchyness. But that means getting the stain off of the shelf.

Trying to limit the level of effort, but match the wood trim in the house.[image]

Comment: Photographs of the damaged area would really help.

Comment: That damage is quite severe so I don't think dilute finish would be enough to even up absorption of stain. I think this is a great candidate for painting, if that's not an option though then wood hardener might be advisable, followed by "gel stain". It's going to be a bit of a job getting back to something close to bare wood though! I would hate to try to do this by sanding alone, even with power sanders.

Comment: Thanks, my partner has a whale of a sander, so that helps!

Comment: FYI - We went ahead and applied polyuerthane it and it actually is "fine" for our needs.